# How to programmatically trigger a D3 drag event?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

So i have some data binded with drag event listeners :

```js
myNodes.enter()
    .append("svg:g")
    .call(d3.behavior.drag()
        .on("drag", function() { 
            console.log(d3.event.dx, d3.event.dy);
        })
    );
```

Now I want to call this onDrag function on a certain node programmatically. I do know the same is possible with standard events by doing

```js
aNode.on("click")() // works
aNode.on("drag")()  // doesn't work
```

Is there any way to do so ? Thanks.

Comment: Can you please set up a jsfiddle? Like that, your code seems to work or I didn't understand what behavior you want.

Comment: I want to trigger the drag function without having to move my mouse a single pixel. As triggering a "click" event is possible without having to actually click, I was wondering if the same is possible with mouse movements. The reason is that my window is dynamically resized so the mouse position is relatively not the same.. Tell me if I'm still not clear and I'll see what I can do with jsfiddle, thanks.

Comment: I asked and answered a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64289838/when-using-d3-how-to-trigger-drag-with-only-mouse-events/64290120#64290120

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Save the callback (the one you pass into the drag handler) in a variable and then call this variable in your other context.

```
var dragCallback = function(){
    console.log(d3.event.dx, d3.event.dy);
};
var dragBehavior = d3.behavior.drag()
    .on("drag", dragCallback);
myNodes.enter()
    .append("g")
    .call(dragBehavior);
    //Call drag method programmatically
dragCallback()
```

Comment: If the goal is to use in testing (not stated in question), then this solution may not be practical. The code may be correct without exposing the callback -- but how to test it?

Comment: Sorry I'm just seeing your answer (not used to SO). That solution would have perfectly solved my problem. I was new to asynchronous programming then, now it totally makes sense, thanks.

Comment: @BausTheBig Hi, my question is similar but not same, it hurts me so much: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29617031/how-to-manually-trigger-the-drag-event-of-d3  Could you help, plz?